# How to get average of each player in recent 5 games

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing `player name`, `total on court` time, and `date` of that game.

[image]

Given a list of players, I want to calculate the average on court time of each player in recent 5 games.

This is how I get average on court time of Aaron Brooks.

```
select `Player Name`, AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`Total on Court`))
from
    (SELECT * FROM nba.`player stat total`
    where `Player Name`='Aaron Brooks'
    order by `date` desc
    limit 5) as t
```

But I have a list of players, it is possible to do in pure sql rather than executing sql in a for-loop in my program?

The players may be in the form `('Aaron Brooks', 'Chris Bosh', 'Andre Miller')` or any other form you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use user-defined variables to get 5 recent records per player group

```
SELECT t.`Player Name` ,
AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(t.`Total on Court`))
 FROM (
SELECT s.*,
@rank:= CASE WHEN @group = s.`Player Name` THEN @rank +1 ELSE 1 END rank ,
@group:= s.`Player Name` g
 FROM
`player stat total` s
JOIN (SELECT @group:='',@rank:='') t
 WHERE s.`Player Name` IN('Aaron Brooks', 'Chris Bosh', 'Andre Miller')
ORDER BY `Player Name`  ,`date` DESC
) t WHERE t.rank <=5
GROUP BY t.`Player Name`
```

Comment: It works dramatically! But I don't understand the part from `SELECT s.*, ...ORDER BY Player Name  ,date DESC`. Can you explain how user-defined variables work here? Or you may point out some references that use similar examples.

Comment: @LoveRight i have used basically a rank query the part `ORDER BY Player Name  ,date DESC` will order the results for each user in descending order of date so i can give rank for user record so for example *Aaron Brooks* latest match will have rank 1 and second latest will have rank of 2 and so on for all entries of *Aaron Brooks* and in `WHERE t.rank <=5` part i have simply filter the results for 5 latest records for each user then a usual group by with aggregation to `AVG` to calculate desired results

Comment: You say `CASE WHEN @group = s.Player Name THEN @rank +1 ELSE 1 END`. When doesn't `@group` equal `PlayerName`?

Comment: @LoveRight yes to give a rank for each row i am checking the player name stored in `@group` is equal to the current one then increment rank else if player is change then give it a rank of one and then same checking will take place for a same player to increment its ranks for each record of player

Comment: So it first runs `@rank:= CASE... end` to see if the player is changed, then do `@group:= s.Player Name g` to update @group to the current player. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT `Player Name`, SUM(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`Total on Court`))) AS Avg FROM nba.`player stat total`
    GROUP BY `Player Name`
    ORDER BY `date` desc
    LIMIT 5) AS t
```